# Intuition for the satellite of a functor

Tags: derived-functors, intuition, ct.category-theory

Occasionally in math I come across constructions or tools that are a bit convoluted. I can look at these constructions and see that they indeed perform the task they were made to do, but sometimes I can't see why they $\textit{should}$ perform this task; why is that the logical thing to choose for the job? Right now, I'm having this issue with the satellite of a functor.

Just to recall, given an additive functor between two abelian categories $F:\mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$, the satellite is another functor $S_-^1(F): \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ defined by

$S_-^1(F)(M) = lim(ker(F(M) \rightarrow F(P)))$

where $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow P \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence with $P$ a projective object. Then a derived functor is formed by taking iterations of the satellite: $S_-^n(F) = S_-(S_-^{n-1}(F))$. More information can be found on [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/satellite).

I am learning about derived functors in a slightly different setting, namely with nonadditive categories where there are not necessarily enough projectives in the category $\mathcal{C}$, and so the definition is modified slightly; perhaps the definition is more transparent in the standard setting.

So my question is

> Is there any intuition for why the satellite is the correct tool to use for obtaining derived functors? If I needed to create a derived functor out of a given functor, is there a logical progression that would lead me to define the satellite?

Comment: I think you want an additive functor between abelian categories.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The different setting in which I'm learning about derived functors also does not require additivity of the functor or abelian categories. It has been changed.

Comment: Don't you want to map from a projective object $P \to M$ and to an injective object $M \to I$?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this can be considered as "intuition", anyway

another way to think about derived functors is the following: given an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, you can define its derived category $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$ (or its variants of bounded complexes in one or both directions). You get $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$ by "localizing" the homotopy category of complexes $\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{A})$, where the objects are complexes in $\mathcal{A}$ and maps are maps of complexes up to homotopy, at the system of quasi-isomorphisms.

There is a natural localization functor $\pi_A:\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{A})\to \mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$. If $F:\mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}$ is your additive functor between abelian categories, and $\mathcal{K}(F):\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{A})\to \mathcal{K}(\mathcal{B})$ is the induced functor, it is natural to ask for an "extension" of $\mathcal{K}(F)$ to the derived category $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$, with values in $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{B})$. In other words this would be a functor $RF:\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})\to \mathcal{D}(\mathcal{B})$, such that $\pi_B \circ \mathcal{K}(F) = RF \circ \pi_A$.

This is not possible to find in general, and the problem is that $\mathcal{K}(F)$ may not send quasi-isomorphisms into quasi-isomorphisms. The best you can ask for is a functor $RF:\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})\to \mathcal{D}(\mathcal{B})$, with a natural transformation $\eta:\pi_B \circ \mathcal{K}(F) \to RF\circ \pi_A$ having a universal property among such functors and natural transformations (this is a particular case of a Kan extension).

Such an $RF$ (unique up to isomorphism) is called the (total) right derived functor of $F$. One way to think about it is as "the" functor between the derived categories which approximates $\mathcal{K}(F)$ in the best possible way. You can recover the single derived functors $R^iF$ by taking the cohomology objects of $RF$. In most cases the derived functor is constructed by using resolutions, by injective (or projective, if you're defining left derived functors) objects, or more generally by suitable subcategories of $\mathcal{A}$.

In your case, if you also assume that $F$ is right exact, then the satellite functors coincide with the (left) derived ones, and so I guess that it follows that they can be calculated by the formulas you wrote.

The idea of the "best approximation" of $\mathcal{K}(F)$ on the derived category seems very natural to me, and a satisfactory answer to the question "why derived functors". If you were asking specifically about satellites, then I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll have to think about this a bit more; I've never worked with Kan extensions before.

Comment: Well, neither have I :) in this case it is just a name, I don't know if there's more to it.

Comment: I agree with you that your answer answers the question of `why derived functors' pretty well. Thanks again for your answer, although I was hoping for something specific about the satellite.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical reference:

F. Ulmer, Satelliten und derivierte funktoren. I, Math. Z. 91 (1966)

http://www.digizeitschriften.de/main/dms/img/?PPN=GDZPPN00239703X

A more simple exposition  can find in Barry Mitchell - Theory of Categories

http://books.google.it/books?id=hgJ3pTQSAd0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=mitchell,+theory+of+categories&source=bl&ots=erlQ8pdHiS&sig=JteX6fmj-qAco7tWA2dmDe-e9_Y&hl=it&ei=prYATeSHJsKi4Qb1n4z0Ag&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAA

Or in classical Cartan Eilenberg "Homological ALgebra"